# Constant predicted values with Logistic Regression in Python

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I'm working on  [Wisconsin dataset for breast cancer](https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/breast-cancer-wisconsin-data) and I have a little problem.

Let me begin with what I've written:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

def loadCSV(filename): 
    ''' 
    function to load dataset 
    '''
    dataset = pd.read_csv(filename)
    
    return np.array(dataset) 

def logistic_func(beta, X): 
    ''' 
    logistic(sigmoid) function 
    '''
    z = np.dot(X.astype(float), beta.T.astype(float))
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z ))

def log_gradient(beta, X, y): 
    ''' 
    logistic gradient function 
    '''
    Z = logistic_func(beta , X) - y.reshape(X.shape[0] , -1)
    Hx = np.dot(Z.T , X)
    return Hx  

def cost_func(beta, X, y): 
    ''' 
    cost function, J 
    '''
    log_func_v = logistic_func(beta, X) 
    y = np.squeeze(y) 
    step1 = y * np.log(log_func_v) 
    step2 = (1 - y) * np.log(1 - log_func_v) 
    final = -step1 - step2 
    return np.mean(final) 

def grad_desc(X, y, beta, lr, converge_change=0.001): 
    ''' 
    gradient descent function 
    '''
    cost = cost_func(beta, X, y) 
    change_cost = 1
    num_iter = 1
      
    while(change_cost > converge_change): 
        old_cost = cost 
        beta = beta - (lr * log_gradient(beta, X, y)) 
        cost = cost_func(beta, X, y) 
        change_cost = old_cost - cost 
        num_iter += 1
      
    return beta, num_iter, cost  

def pred_values(beta, X): 
    ''' 
    function to predict labels 
    '''
    pred_prob = logistic_func(beta, X) 
    pred_value = np.where(pred_prob >= .5, 1, 0) 
    return np.squeeze(pred_value)
```

And this is my main:

```
if __name__ == "__main__": 
        # load the dataset 
        dataset = loadCSV(r'..\...\data.csv')       
        
        # splitting the non-normalized data into test(almost 25%) and train(almost 75%)    
        X1_Train = dataset[round(len(dataset)*25/100):, 2:]
        X1_Test = dataset[:round(len(dataset)*25/100), 2:]
        
        # stacking columns wth all ones in feature matrix  
        X1_Test = np.hstack((np.matrix(np.ones(X1_Test.shape[0])).T, X1_Test))
        X1_Train = np.hstack((np.matrix(np.ones(X1_Train.shape[0])).T, X1_Train))
    
        # general response vector 
        y = dataset[:, 1]
        for i in range(len(y)):
            if y[i] == "M":
                y[i] = 1
            else:
                y[i] = 0
        
        # response vectors for training & testing
        y_Train = dataset[round(len(dataset)*25/100):, 1]
        y_Test = dataset[:round(len(dataset)*25/100), 1]
        
        # initial beta values 
        beta1 = np.matrix(np.zeros(X1_Train.shape[1]))

        # beta value after running gradient descent 
        beta1, num_iter1_Train, cost1_Train = grad_desc(X1_Train, y_Train, beta1, 0.001)
        
        # predicted labels 
        y_pred1_Test = pred_values(beta1, X1_Test) 

        # number of correctly predicted labels 
        print("- Non-Normalized dataset \t Model Accuracy:", np.sum(y_Test == y_pred1_Test)/len(y_Test)*100, '\b% (Testing dataset, alpha = 0.001)')
```

The problem is `y_pred1_Test` always have 1's and that's not what should be done!

I tried to find out what goes wrong and it all happens when calling `pred_values`, so I think my problem is related to the sigmoid function?

I don't know, but it seems right for me! So I can't think of any other mistake I did.
Any ideas?

Comment: Your assumption is correct, the problem is with the sigmoid function. Due to negative exponential behaviour, it's returning 0 for all values of z and saturates the sigmoid function at 1. Read about it here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function

Edit: Maybe you can try and normalize Z values before using them in the sigmoid function?

Comment: It's requested not to normalize the data and I ran out of ideas!

Comment: What about normalizing just the Z values?

Comment: Which is normalizing the ```X1_Test```, right? That's the one I cannot normalize

Answer (score 0):

`beta1` is an array of zeros when you pass it to `pred_values` so it eventually gets to `logistic_func` where it dot multiplied by x, which `x*0 = 0`

```
z = np.dot(X.astype(float), beta.T.astype(float))
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z ))
```

which makes the rest of math work out like this

```
z = x * 0
z = 0

return = 1 / (1 + z)
return = 1 / (1)
return = 1
```

Comment: but beta1 actually has data? try to ```print(beta1)``` before ```y_pred1_Test = pred_values(beta1, X1_Test)```

Comment: `beta` inside of `pred_values` prints  "[[nan nan nan ......  nan]]" Bata1 is first initialized with all zeros in your main function. no actual data is ever loaded into it.